# Do I have to write PHP code in my HTML documents AND include it on EVERY page or can I use an external file just like css/js?

Tags: php, html, external

Is this the way to write your PHP? I would like to know if I can use an external file to keep things seperated, as I like to be organised. Also do I need to store my entire content in the XAMPP folder in Windows(C:) or just the PHP files? Haven't been able to find a decent answer on these questions. Help greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagestyling.css">
</head>

<body>

<?php
    include('/path/to/file.php'); 
?>

//scripts go here
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT EXAMPLE:**

```
<?php 
    //form validation code here
?>   

<div id="content">

        <form class="applyform" method="POST" action="">

        <h3>Please fill in your application below.</h3>
            <p>
                <label>In-game username:</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>*Including CAPITALISED letters (if you have it)</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Irl Nickname:</label>
                    <input name="nickname" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>(So we know what to call you)</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Game:</label>
                    <select name="selectgame">
                        <option value="Heroes of Atlan">Heroes of Atlan
                        <option value="Knights and Dragons">Knights and Dragons
                    </select>
                    <h6>(What game do you want to join us in?)</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email Address:</label>
                    <input name="emailaddress" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>*Used for GroupMe and confirmation email.</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Level:</label>
                    <input name="charlevel" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>(Your main character level)</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Arena rank:</label>
                    <input name="arenarank" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>(E.g. Heroes of Atlan: (1) 3358 or K&ampD: RIBBON E)</h6>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Referral code:</label>
                    <input name="refcode" type="text"></input>
                    <h6>(Knights and Dragons only, e.g. "XU5-CP3-SK9")</h6>
            </p>
            <h5>Please check that the information that you have entered is correct before proceeding.</h5>
            <input id="submitbutton" name="applySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

        </form>

    </div> <!-- end of content -->
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do!? Do you want to add external file to you code or want to fetch data of external file?

Comment: include('/path/to/file.php'); will do it

Comment: The documentation should really help you, it includes explanation and code examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: `I would like to know if I can use an external file to keep things seperated` - Yes you can. You'll have to use `include 'path/to/file'` to reference it `Also do I need to store my entire content in the XAMPP folder in Windows(C:) or just the PHP files` - Yes, all files go into the `XAMPP/htdocs/<your_folder>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a php file like this

**include_file.php**

```
<?php

//some php code
?>


some html here
```

now you can include it in every page you require. like this

```
<?php


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagestyling.css">
</head>

<body>

<?php
include("include_file.php");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

you can also use [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) as per your requirement.

and learn tutorial

Comment: So the code would look somewhat like the example I added?

Answer (score 0):

Usualy you would write for exempe the header in the seperate header.php file and then include it in your main file:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```